# Is binding with variables essential when using memory with python?

Tags: python-3.11

```
instance1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I am sure that the above code takes up memory.
However, do I use memory even if I enter the list literal as below in Python Interactive shell without any intention and press enter?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Furthermore, what happens in the following cases?

```
[1,1,1][0] = 100
```

Does index 0 actually change to 100?
At the point where I ran the code above without binding with a variable, I don't know how to access it again and see what happened to index 0.

At least this runs without an error message, but I don't know what this means or what works internally. I want to know.

I'm even confused about what I want to know, so I'm careful to express it.
Maybe I wanted to know, what happens when I access it directly without binding to a variable, and what it means.